# Reconfigure mongodb connection on each request

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using an external module on a webapp, meaning I can't change that code, that uses Spring Data. It starts using some properties like `${mongoURI}` and `${mongoDB}` to connect to a database and feed its repositories, which you access through a `Service` wiring it to your `Controllers`.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that we have a database per user, therefore I need a different connection for each user, but I'm not sure how Spring supports it.

I import this service like this:

```
<!-- This is in the imported jar -->
<import resource="classpath:/service-mongo-context.xml" />

<!-- This is in my folder structure -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/mongodb-config.properties" />
```

And then in my `Controller` I just:

```
@Autowired private Service service;
```

I would like to know if it is possible to rebuild the entire service each time you receive a connection passing a different `${mongoURI}` and `${mongoDB}`, perhaps changing variables in `@Autowired`.

Comment: I am not completely sure what is the objective: you want a single instance to self-reconfigure each time URL and credentials change? Wouldn't it be better if you have multiple service instances, one per each Mongo URI? Whilst from a technical perspective this is feasiblem, I wonder if it architecturally acceptable in your case?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is that we have a database per user, therefore I need a different connection for each user, but I'm not sure how Spring supports it. So single instance or multiple instance is ok for me.

Comment: I would then suggest you to try the "session" scope or the "request" scope, depending on your clustering/HA/lifecycle needs.

Comment: Is that the Controller scope? If not, is there a way to configure the wiring?

Also, how to set the Properties on runtime?

Comment: Oh mate, sorry, I did not notice that the "import resource" was in the JAR (well, that can be hijaked). No, you need to override it in the bean definition.

Comment: by the way, can you share the service interface? I wonder why if a service hasnt been designed to support multiple DBs then why you want to force it to.

Comment: It just exposes connection info through the properties I listed above. On wiring, it connects and does its thing, exposing some business logic functions (like services usually do).

Comment: If it does so little, you could simply avoid using it.

Comment: No can do, it's client's requisite ;)